# End Windows application (but not simply terminating the process)

Tags: windows

I would like to end a certain Windows application gracefully, without using a mouse or keyboard shortcuts. I also don't want to simply end the application's process. (Hence, "gracefully".)
In other words, I would like to invoke the application's own "exit procedure". How do I do this?

I don't mind getting down and dirty with code and dubious hacks, I just have no idea where to start… Using AutoHotkey to simulate the key presses required to end the application is not good enough for me. :P

Comment: (I'm confused why this question was migrated from super user to here… It's not necessarily a programming question…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Task Manager uses the EndTask function for this: [EndTask Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This function first sends nice WM_CLOSE messages.

Comment: @Protector - It first try to play it nice, and then harder. It you really need to close the app, that's a good way. See here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/22/191123.aspx. Otherwise, here is the official way: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178893

Comment: I first shrugged off this answer due to the, "[it] forcibly closes the specified window"-line, but after consideration it seems this is pretty much what I'm looking for. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Find the taskbar windows owned by the process (there's usually only one) and send them WM_CLOSE messages.